# How to find datetime list that fall in specific date range

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime list and I want to get the time list that fall in the specific date range which is 4 hours before.

Currently, I read all the DateTime from XML file with following code:

```
        Xmldatabase database = new Xmldatabase();
        foreach (var data in database.dt.DateInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.LastUpdatedTime);
        }
```

Output that I read from XML file:

```
11/09/2021 09:17:15Z
11/09/2021 09:26:15Z
...
11/10/2021 02:36:26Z
11/10/2021 04:10:18Z
11/10/2021 04:35:30Z
```

Output that I want that fall in past 4 hours only:

```
  11/10/2021 04:10:18Z
  11/10/2021 04:35:30Z
```

How should I continue with the following code and get the DateTime that only fall in the past 4 hours? For the DateTime that fall in past 4 hours, I need to do something.

```
string query = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-4).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:00Z");
```

Comment: DateTime.Parse(data.LastUpdatedTime) <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4)

Comment: Do you mean you want to query the XML, or query the list once loaded into C#? Please show your mdoels.

Comment: @Llama Hi, I want to query the list once it load in C#

Answer (score 1):

```
    Xmldatabase database = new Xmldatabase();
    foreach (var data in database.dt.DateInfo)
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(data.LastUpdatedTime) <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.LastUpdatedTime);
 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it comes out an error which is 'System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime' at this line[ (DateTime.Parse(data.LastUpdatedTime) <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4)) ]. Since it already convert with DateTime.Parse, I not sure why it come out with this error.

Comment: That's a problem with your data or your parsing mechanism.

Comment: Try this piece of code, and then have some reading about DateTime parsing in c#


 string format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
 DateTime dt;
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data.LastUpdatedTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
 {
         if (dt <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.LastUpdatedTime);
 
        }
 }